# void pointer, and re casting to required type

Tags: c, linux, struct, void-pointers

I want to allocate memory for in_array as double array of length 100, how can i do it as a function in the simplest form.

```
typedef struct{
int message;
void*in_array;
}data_pack;
```

im trying like this to allocate memory for double array of 100 elements

```
struct data_pack* createpack()
{
struct data_pack* packet = (struct data_pack*)malloc(sizeof(struct data_pack));
packet->in_array= (double **)malloc(100 * sizeof(double));

return packet ;
}
```

is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of issues:

Because you used a typedef, you don't need to add 'struct' in front of your data type:

`data_pack* packet = malloc(sizeof(data_pack));`

And because you've declared *in_array* as a void ptr, you shouldn't cast it to a *double*:

```
packet->in_array= malloc(100 * sizeof(double));
```

(In fact, [don't cast the result of malloc to anything..](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/5639126))

EDIT:

In response to the comment, *if you wanted an array of type double* you can change the declaration of data_pack to:

```
typedef struct{
int message;
double *in_array;
}data_pack;
```

Then treat it as an array:

```
packet->in_array[0] = 0.1;
packet->in_array[1] = 0.2;
```

and so on; but *if you wanted an array of pointers to double* then you change the declaration of in_array to:

```
typedef struct{
int message;
double **in_array;
}data_pack;
```

And, because you are now storing an array of *pointers that point to doubles* instead of doubles, you change your malloc of in_array to:

```
packet->in_array= malloc(100 * sizeof(double *));
```

Then, you can add pointers to doubles to that array, for example:

```
double foo = 0.1;
packet->in_array[0] = &foo;
```

EDIT 2

To copy the contents of one array to another, use **memcpy**:

```
#include <string.h>

double foo[100] = {0.1,0.2};
memcpy( packet->in_array, foo, sizeof(foo));
```

It works both ways:

```
double foo[100] = {};
memcpy( foo, packet->in_array, sizeof(foo));
```

Comment: of course, you could go the other way and remove the typedef, and declare in_array as a ptr to double

Comment: what if if i need to assign a double array of 100 elements to packet->in_array, how can i do that

Comment: thank you so much, to make this clear , i have an array say, double data[100]; so how can i assign data to packet->in_array, can we do it like this 
packet->in_array=data;   ?

and how can i take data out of my struct?

Comment: **cough** **cough** quote: `As a clarification, note that I said "you don't cast", not "you don't need to cast".`

Comment: @Shark oooo sorry, you are perfectly correct, I have misquoted you; i'll change it :)

Comment: hey, it wasn't my answer, i just looked it up and noticed the discrepancy :D

Comment: why i used void* is that, i can allocate memory of double if im going to assign a double to it, or i can allocate memory of int, if im assigning int to it. for one particular code i will be assigning only one type

Comment: you can do that, it's perfectly valid, but you have to be very careful in keeping track of whats what; it's much safer to do double *double_in_array; int * int_in_array; etc, and keep things seperate, because of the "what can go wrong, will go wrong" principle :)

Comment: if i define in_array  as void*in_array, and another double array as double data[100]; can i assign it as packet->in_array=data;
or memcpy( packet->in_array, data, sizeof(data));

Comment: you can do a cast in this case: packet->in_array = (void *)data; if you use this approach you dont malloc packet->in_array; you are only storing an address in packet

Comment: sorry for repeated doubts, im not familiar with this, i assigned with packet->in_array = (void *)data, but when i try to print data on console, its showing "0". my printf statement is printf("data is %f",packet->(double*)in_array[0]);
"im putting star but its not showing in comment"

Comment: Ah, ok, sorry try this, be careful about brackets: packet->in_array = data;
    printf("%f", ((double *)(packet->in_array))[1] );

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218829/discussion-between-altris-and-secret-squirrel).

Answer (score 0):

If you want `in_array` to be an array of `double`, then declare it as

```
double *in_array;
```

and allocate it as

```
packet->in_array = malloc( sizeof *packet->in_array * 100 );
```

Yes, `malloc` returns `void *`, but in C a `void *` can be assigned to any other object pointer type (and vice-versa) without needing a cast<sup>1</sup>.  And, you were casting the result to "pointer to pointer to `double`", which doesn’t match what you said you wanted.

---

1. This is *not* true in C++, but if you’re writing C++ you shouldn’t be using `malloc` anyway.